# Using formulae, take the amt in cell range E21 to E27 from the below table matching Month and Category

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Month | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | $90,004.84 | $21,305.57 | $8,750.15 | $6,710.85 | $2,758.08 |
| Feb | $143,249.41 | $29,221.38 | $12,277.30 | $14,521.09 | $8,188.73 |
| Mar | $353,490.84 | $54,955.47 | $23,080.23 | $23,576.57 | $12,708.97 |
| Apr | $141,635.09 | $21,577.78 | $9,422.79 | $3,469.29 | $4,152.48 |
| May | $59,258.16 | $23,497.80 | $5,720.68 | $3,994.12 | $786.53 |
| Jun | $167,885.79 | $43,609.28 | $24,769.75 | $16,286.47 | $8,118.55 |
| Jul | $140,934.09 | $11,535.66 | $11,554.36 | $5,890.40 | $325.88 |

| Month | Category | Amt |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May | d |  |  |  |
| Apr | a |  |  |  |
| Jun | c |  |  |  |
| May | b |  |  |  |
| Jan | e |  |  |  |
| Jul | a |  |  |  |
| Feb | c |  |  |  |

i am using this one =VLOOKUP(C21&D21,$C$8:$H$15,4,0)

Answer (score 2):

You need `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination. Try-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$F$8,MATCH($A13,$A$2:$A$8,0),MATCH($B13,$B$1:$F$1,0))
```

[image]